# Python comparing two strings to differences

Tags: python, string, list

I currently have two lists:

```
str1 = ['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg', 'test3.jpg']
str2 = ['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg']
```

As you may well notice, test3.jpg is missing from str2. Is there a way I can compare str2 with str1 and find the missing pieces?

Comment: That's correct. Sorry. I did not know they were called arrays. I guess that explains why it was so hard finding anything on Google..

Comment: In Pythons those *things* are called lists.

Answer (score 0):

well. those are actually 2 list of strings you got there.

One simple way to compare 'em would be to:

```
missing = [x for x in str1 if x not in str2]
missing
```

Out:

```
['test3.jpg']
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in type `set`

```
str1 = ['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg', 'test3.jpg']
str2 = ['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg']
s1 = set(str1)
s2 = set(str2)
print(s1-s2)
```

From there you can easily create function:

```
def difference(list1,list2):
    return set(list1)-set(list2)
```

If you want to create difference between **both** of them you can do the following:
For data :

```
str1 = ['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg', 'test3.jpg']
str2 = ['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg', 'test4.jpg']
```

Funcion would be:

```
def difference(list1,list2):
    return (set(list1)-set(list2)) | (set(list2)-set(list1))
```

Or :

```
def difference(list1,list2):
    return set(list1).symmetric_difference(set(list2))
```

Outputs:

> {'test3.jpg', 'test4.jpg'}

All is documented here: [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Answer (score 0):

The solution using ***Set*** difference operator:

```
str1 = ['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg', 'test3.jpg']
str2 = ['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg']

diff = list(set(str1) - set(str2))
# the same can be achieved with set.difference(*others) method:
# diff = list(set(str1).difference(set(str2))) 
print(diff)
```

The output:

```
['test3.jpg']
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set.difference