# Find difference in two rows of string in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column that has a string with comma separated items.

```
col1
apple, banana, kiwi
apple, banana
banana
```

I want to make a second column 'col2' that shows the difference between each row.

So I'm trying to turn each row into a set, and subtracting it from the previous row as referred to here: [Python comparing two strings to differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957912/python-comparing-two-strings-to-differences)

```
df['col2'] = set(df["col1"].shift(1)) - set(df["col1"])
```

However I get this error message: "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index".
What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

EDIT:
expected output

```
col1                           col2
apple, banana, kiwi             
apple, banana                  kiwi
banana                         apple
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy done. so it's supposed to show the difference between the previous and current row in col2.

Comment: and if the difference is more than one, do you return a list/tuple ?

Comment: @sammywemmy yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df["temp"] = df.col1.str.replace("\s+", "").str.split(",")
```

Assign value to `difference` column:

```
df['difference'] = [    ""
                     if isinstance(last, float) or (not set(last).difference(first))
                     else tuple(set(last).difference(first))
                     if len(set(last).difference(first)) > 1
                     else min(set(last).difference(first))
                     for first, last in zip(df.temp, df["temp"].shift())
                  ]
df.drop('temp', axis=1)

    col1                   difference
0   apple, banana, kiwi 
1   apple, banana              kiwi
2   banana                    apple
```

Comment: I get a syntax error at outcome := pointing at the :. did you mean to write something else?

Comment: oh. that's the walrus operator. python 3.8 I believe. It makes it a bit easier to stop repeating words. I'll edit it if your version is < 3.8

Comment: now I get a "valueerror: min() arg is an empty sequence" at "for first, last in".

Comment: for the same data you shared?

Comment: the data I shared here is a representative of the 5k+ data I have... am I getting this error because there might not be a difference in some rows?

Comment: and if there is no difference, then an empty string?

Comment: yes correct. Thank you for taking the time to work with me on this.

Comment: that worked wonders, thank you so much for your help. I didn't realize this would get more complicated than what I had initially.